# Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'props') in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I can not seem to get props working for passing information from my child class up to my parent class. What I am trying to do, is to detect what dropdown menu option someone has chosen, send that information up to the parent class which then takes the chosen option and runs a call to backend that then returns a list of database items which match the chosen option.

Below is the child class:

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import SEPractices from "../dummydata/SEPractices"

  const optionItems = SEPractices.map((SEPractice) =>
                <option key={SEPractice.practice}>{SEPractice.practice}</option>
            );
  const Dropdown = () => {
  const [selectValue, setValue] = useState("")
    
  const handleSelect = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setValue(e.target.value);
    this.props.handlePractice(e.target.value);
}

    return (
        <div>
             <select value={selectValue} onChange={handleSelect}> 
                
               <option value="dummyData">
                 Select an SE Practice
                 </option>
                {optionItems}
             </select>
         </div>

    )
  }
  export default Dropdown;
```

Below is the parent class:

```
import React,{useState} from "react";
import Styles from "../components/tablestyle.js";
import Table from "../components/evidencetable.js";
import tablecolumns from "../components/tablecolumns.js";
import Dropdown from "../components/Dropdown.js";
import axios from "axios";

//const dbArticles = [];
class SEPractice extends React.Component{
  /*constructor(props){
  this.state = {dbArticles: []};
  this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
  this.getArticles = this.getArticles.bind(this);
  this.practice = this.practice.bind(this);
  }*/
  state={
    dbArticles: []
  }
  
  handlePractice (Option) {
  
    console.log("hi");

    // axios.get(`https://protected-plains-77403.herokuapp.com/api/articles/${Option}`)
    axios.get(`https://localhost:5000/api/articles/${Option}`)
    .then((response) =>{
      const data = response.data;
      this.setState({dbArticles: data});
      console.log('state', this.state);
    })
    .catch(()=>{
      alert('error retrieving data');
    });
  }

  componentDidMount = () =>{
    this.getArticles();
  }
  getArticles = () =>{
    axios.get('https://protected-plains-77403.herokuapp.com/api/articles')
    .then((response) =>{
      const data = response.data;
      this.setState({dbArticles: data});
      console.log('state', this.state);
    })
    .catch(()=>{
      alert('error retrieving data');
    });
  }
/*practice =() =>{
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState('');
  const practiceHandler = (e) =>{
    setSelected(e);
  }
}*/
render() {
    return (

      <div>
        <h2>Select SE Practice to get evidence for the claimed benefits</h2>
            <Dropdown onDropdown={this.handlePractice}/>
            <Styles>
                <Table
                data={this.state.dbArticles}
                columns={tablecolumns}
                />
            </Styles>
      </div>
    );
}
}
export default SEPractice;
```

I followed a few articles and stack overflow blogs and they all say to do this.props.method which I did:

```
  const handleSelect = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setValue(e.target.value);
    this.props.handlePractice(e.target.value);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the parent class, you are not correctly binding the method in the constructor. You need the following:

```
class SEPractice extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       dbArticles: []
    }

    this.handlePractice = this.handlePractice.bind(this);
  }
```

The `handlePractice` method is now bound to the parent component. When you pass it to the child component, you assign it to the property `onDropdown`. You need to then access it correctly from the child component using the `onDropdown` property to which you have assigned it. Note, because the child component is a **functional** component, we do not use `this.props`, like you did in the parent component which is a **class** component. Like so:

```
  const Dropdown = (props) => { //Notice here we passed props into the function that generates the component
    const [selectValue, setValue] = useState("")
    
    const handleSelect = (e) => {
      console.log(e.target.value);
      setValue(e.target.value);
      props.onDropdown(e.target.value); //Not this.props
    }

    return (
        <div>
             <select value={selectValue} onChange={handleSelect}> 
                
               <option value="dummyData">
                 Select an SE Practice
                 </option>
                {optionItems}
             </select>
         </div>

    )
  }
  export default Dropdown;

}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I really appreciate it a lot! When I make the changes, I still get the `'props' is not defined  no-undef` error in the child class.

Comment: When does this error appear? When you attempt to make a selection from the dropdown?

Comment: It makes an error on runtime. So as soon as I start the Node.js server it says failed to compile followed by the error.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I missed the (props)! It is now working!! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You are not receiving any props in the component as you are not allowing for the parameter and also acting on the incorrect prop name:

```
const Dropdown = () => { // missing props here
  const [selectValue, setValue] = useState("")
    
  const handleSelect = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setValue(e.target.value);
    this.props.handlePractice(e.target.value); // problem here
}

    return (
        <div>
             <select value={selectValue} onChange={handleSelect}> 
                
               <option value="dummyData">
                 Select an SE Practice
                 </option>
                {optionItems}
             </select>
         </div>

    )
  }
  export default Dropdown;
```

Update to receive the props:

```
const Dropdown = (props) => {
  const [selectValue, setValue] = useState("")
    
  const handleSelect = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setValue(e.target.value);
    props.onDropdown(e.target.value); // note correct name
}

    return (
        <div>
             <select value={selectValue} onChange={handleSelect}> 
                
               <option value="dummyData">
                 Select an SE Practice
                 </option>
                {optionItems}
             </select>
         </div>

    )
  }
  export default Dropdown;
```

[Codesandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-69322127-1b4i9?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I made the change but still seem to get the `'props' is not defined  no-undef` error. Thanks for the comment as well!

Comment: See the demo, better to stay with classes or functional components, not mix both imo.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your code to

```
const handleSelect = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setValue(e.target.value);
    this.props.onDropdown(e.target.value);
}
```

The reason is because on the dropdown component you named the prop `onDropdown`

When you are trying to console.log your state after doing `setState` do it like so

```
      const data = response.data;
      this.setState({dbArticles: data},() => console.log('state', this.state));
    })
```

the reason is that setState is asynchronous and the second argument is a callback that fires after state has actually been set.

Comment: Thank you for that imporovement on the code! It makes a lot of sense. I do still get the `'props' is not defined  no-undef` error when I changed it to onDropdown.